# TensorFlow Keras input error "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning, vgg-net

I am trying to train a VGG19 model and fine tuning it.
My train dataset contains 35990 images and test dataset contains 3720 images.
During the training I am experiencing this error : **"ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"**

Can anyone tell me what does it mean and how to solve it?

shape of **train1_data : (35990,224,224,3)**
shape of **test1_data : (3720,224,224,3)**

**Code:**

```
from keras.applications import VGG16
vgg_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))


for layer in vgg_model.layers[:15]:
    layer.trainable = False
# Make sure you have frozen the correct layers
for i, layer in enumerate(vgg_model.layers):
    print(i, layer.name, layer.trainable)

x = vgg_model.output
x = Flatten()(x) 
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x) 
x = Dense(264, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(372, activation='softmax')(x) 
transfer_model = Model(inputs=vgg_model.input, outputs=x)

from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
lr_reduce = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_accuracy', factor=0.6, patience=8, verbose=1, mode='max', min_lr=5e-5)
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('vgg16_finetune.h15', monitor= 'val_accuracy', mode= 'max', save_best_only = True, verbose= 1)

from keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models, Model, optimizers
learning_rate= 5e-5
transfer_model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=Adam(lr=learning_rate), metrics=["accuracy"])
history = transfer_model.fit(train1_data, batch_size = 15, epochs=5, validation_data=test1_data, callbacks=[lr_reduce,checkpoint])
```

**Here is the full traceback:**

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-8fee2cdfeca2> in <module>
      3 learning_rate= 5e-5
      4 transfer_model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=Adam(lr=learning_rate), metrics=["accuracy"])
----> 5 history = transfer_model.fit(train1_data, batch_size = 15, epochs=5, validation_data=test1_data, callbacks=[lr_reduce,checkpoint])

~\Anaconda3\envs\OCR_ENV\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
   1156         # Prepare validation data.
   1157         do_validation = False
-> 1158         if validation_data:
   1159             do_validation = True
   1160             if len(validation_data) == 2:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

**Train1_data and Teas1_data**

```
import cv2

train_data = []
label = []

IMG_SIZE=32

minRange = np.array([0,138,67],np.uint8)  
maxRange = np.array([255,173,133],np.uint8) 

def create_testing_data():
   
    for classs in CLASSES:  

        path = os.path.join(DATADIR,classs)  
        class_num = str(CLASSES.index(classs))          
        for img in os.listdir(path):  
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img))
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))    
                new_array=np.array(new_array)
                #new_array=np.array(image)
                #print(np.shape(new_array))
                new_array = new_array.astype('float32')
                new_array /= 255 
                
                train_data.append(new_array)  
                label.append(class_num)
               
         
            
create_testing_data()
print(len(predicted))
print(len(train_data))
np.shape(train_data)
```

**Traceback after adding train and test labels in fit.**

```
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models, Model, optimizers
learning_rate= 5e-5
transfer_model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=Adam(lr=learning_rate), metrics=["accuracy"])
history = transfer_model.fit(train1_data, label, batch_size = 15, epochs=5, validation_data=(test1_data,label1), callbacks=[lr_reduce,checkpoint])




AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-c850ac7c8c6d> in <module>
      3 learning_rate= 5e-5
      4 transfer_model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=Adam(lr=learning_rate), metrics=["accuracy"])
----> 5 history = transfer_model.fit(train1_data, label, batch_size = 15, epochs=5, validation_data=(test1_data,label1), callbacks=[lr_reduce,checkpoint])

~\Anaconda3\envs\OCR_ENV\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
   1152             sample_weight=sample_weight,
   1153             class_weight=class_weight,
-> 1154             batch_size=batch_size)
   1155 
   1156         # Prepare validation data.

~\Anaconda3\envs\OCR_ENV\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
    619                 feed_output_shapes,
    620                 check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
--> 621                 exception_prefix='target')
    622 
    623             # Generate sample-wise weight values given the `sample_weight` and

~\Anaconda3\envs\OCR_ENV\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
     97         data = data.values if data.__class__.__name__ == 'DataFrame' else data
     98         data = [data]
---> 99     data = [standardize_single_array(x) for x in data]
    100 
    101     if len(data) != len(names):

~\Anaconda3\envs\OCR_ENV\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     97         data = data.values if data.__class__.__name__ == 'DataFrame' else data
     98         data = [data]
---> 99     data = [standardize_single_array(x) for x in data]
    100 
    101     if len(data) != len(names):

~\Anaconda3\envs\OCR_ENV\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py in standardize_single_array(x)
     32                 'Got tensor with shape: %s' % str(shape))
     33         return x
---> 34     elif x.ndim == 1:
     35         x = np.expand_dims(x, 1)
     36     return x

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

**Input shape error in dense layer**
I have removed str from the Train and test label input and converted it into np array.
**CODE**

```
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models, Model, optimizers
learning_rate= 5e-5
transfer_model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=Adam(lr=learning_rate), metrics=["accuracy"])
history = transfer_model.fit(train1_data, train1_label, batch_size = 15, epochs=5, validation_data=(test1_data,test1_label), callbacks=[lr_reduce,checkpoint])
```

**Traceback**

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-4564124fa363> in <module>
      3 learning_rate= 5e-5
      4 transfer_model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=Adam(lr=learning_rate), metrics=["accuracy"])
----> 5 history = transfer_model.fit(train1_data, train1_label, batch_size = 15, epochs=5, validation_data=(test1_data,test1_label), callbacks=[lr_reduce,checkpoint])

~\Anaconda3\envs\OCR_ENV\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
   1152             sample_weight=sample_weight,
   1153             class_weight=class_weight,
-> 1154             batch_size=batch_size)
   1155 
   1156         # Prepare validation data.

~\Anaconda3\envs\OCR_ENV\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
    619                 feed_output_shapes,
    620                 check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
--> 621                 exception_prefix='target')
    622 
    623             # Generate sample-wise weight values given the `sample_weight` and

~\Anaconda3\envs\OCR_ENV\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    133                         ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
    134                         str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
--> 135                         'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    136                 if not check_batch_axis:
    137                     data_shape = data_shape[1:]

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_10 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (35990, 1)
```

**Model Summary**

```
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 224, 224, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 112, 112, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 56, 56, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 28, 28, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 14, 14, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 7, 7, 512)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 25088)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 512)               12845568  
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 264)               135432    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 372)               98580     
=================================================================
Total params: 27,794,268
Trainable params: 20,159,004
Non-trainable params: 7,635,264
```

Comment: "Can anyone tell me what does it mean and how to solve it?" What happened when you tried copying and pasting it [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ValueError%3A+The+truth+value+of+an+array+with+more+than+one+element+is+ambiguous.+Use+a.any()+or+a.all())?

Comment: How are you creating `train1_data` and `test1_data`? I suspect the issue lies there. You should convert to `tf.data.Dataset` instead of passing the arrays.

Comment: I am reading the images and storing them in an array and converting it into a numpy array.

Comment: I have googled the error and it shows that error might be of some boolean array but I have not used any such and don't know about it.

Comment: @AanandRathore modify the the question by adding train1data, train1label, test1label and test1data

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) the `fit()` method takes a tuple of the form `(data, labels)` for `validation_data` whereas you're providing just the NumPy array, so when it checks for validation data the comparison causes that exception. You also haven't provided training labels to `fit()`.

Try converting your last line to

```py
history = transfer_model.fit(train1_data, train1_labels, batch_size = 15, epochs=5, validation_data=(test1_data, test1_labels), callbacks=[lr_reduce,checkpoint])
```

and see if that avoids the error you're getting.

In general I recommend using `tf.data.Dataset` for handling datasets and inputting to the `fit()` function as I mentioned in an [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63760764/10044861).

**EDIT:** As we discussed in the comments, two other things needed to change were using `int` for labels instead of `str`:

```py
class_num = CLASSES.index(classs)
```

and using `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` loss instead of `categorical_crossentropy`:

```py
transfer_model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=Adam(lr=learning_rate), metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried giving Training Labels but the error changed to " 'str' object has no attribute 'ndim'". I have added the full traceback of the new error above. Is it occuring because of the input shape and side of the model? How can I solve this?

Comment: I think it's because you have your labels as `str` instead of `int`. Just use `class_num = CLASSES.index(classs)` without `str`. And make the labels into a NumPy array.

Comment: Thank you for help. It worked but the vaule error changed to " ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_10 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (35990, 1) ". My array sizes are : train1_data = (35990,225,225,3), test1_data = (3720,224,224,3), train1_label = (35990,), test1_label = (3720,). I have tried giving shape to last dense layer as "x = Dense(372, input_shape=(35990,224,224,3), activation='softmax')(x)" nut it seems not to be working. I have added full traceback above. Is the problem in train1_data and test1_data or train1_label and test1_label?

Comment: What does the output of `transfer_model.summary()` show? This should indicate the expected output shapes of each layer, including your finetuning layers.

Comment: summary shows `dense_12 (Dense)             (None, 372)               191862`. I think the problem is that dense layer is expecting an input with 372rows and it is getting one with 1 row? Is it correct? How to correct the mismatch?

Comment: I have posted the whole summary.

Comment: So one thing is to use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` loss instead of `categorical_crossentropy` because you're giving it a single label instead of a one-hot encoding. But that seems different to the exception you described. I tried your code myself and it worked fine when using `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`, so there must be something odd you're doing with your input/validation data.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping out @ AaronKeesing. `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`  solved the problem, didn't need to change train and test array and labels further.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include what we've discussed in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

you have a final dense layer with 372 nodes. That means you have 372 wide output. Your loss="categorical_crossentropy". So do are your labels 1 hot encoded? Are you trying to do classification? How many classes do you have?

Comment: Yes. I am trying a 372 class classification. Is "Categorical_crossentropy" loss is not appropriate for this kind of work?

Comment: yes it is fine as long as your labels are one hot encoded