# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_7 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 1024)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tf.keras

New Python developer here. I looked at other similar posts here but i'm not able to get it right. Would appreciate any help.

```
print('X_train:', X_train.shape)
print('y_train:', y_train1.shape)
print('X_test:', X_train.shape)
print('y_test:', y_train1.shape)
```

X_train: (42000, 32, 32)
y_train: (42000,)
X_test: (42000, 32, 32)
y_test: (42000,)

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
def featuremodel() :
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=4, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[0],32,64)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=3))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=4, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(len(y_train[0]), activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer='adadelta',      
          metrics=['acc'])
    model.summary()
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 10, validation_data = (X_test,y_test))
```

return model

ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_7 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 1024)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: : expected min\_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: \[None, 2584\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63760734/valueerror-input-0-of-layer-sequential-is-incompatible-with-the-layer-expect)

Comment: yes, that looks right, i get the issue - but can't figure what i'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Your input shape is not correct. you have 42000 samples which each one has 32,32 shape.  So the input shape should be (32,32).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input shape you have specified should be changed. Your input has 42000 samples and each one has `(32,32)` shape. You should not pass number of samples `(42000)` to input layer, and you should add a channel dimension. So the input shape should be `(32,32,1)`.

The modified code should be like this:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

# test data
X_train = tf.random.uniform((42000,32,32))  
y_train1 = tf.random.uniform((42000,))

X_train = tf.expand_dims(X_train, axis=3)    #add channel axis (42000,32,32) => (42000,32,32,1) 

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=4, activation='relu', input_shape=(32,32,1))) #change input shape
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=3))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
#last layer should have output like your y data. in this case it should be 1, since you have 1 y for each sample
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))  
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
      optimizer='adadelta',      
      metrics=['acc'])
model.summary()
model.fit(X_train, y_train1, epochs = 10) #, validation_data = (X_test,y_test))
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps explain what i was doing wrong.